# ngFor not working with subscriptions - Angualr

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngfor

I want to display data from an Api into a div using `*ngFor` but did not work, I am kinda sure the problem is that the variable which I use to store api data in undefined because the the api takes some time to get the response. I tried lots of possible solutions but non of them worked!
Any help?

---

here's my service file.

```
getFlightsData(from,to,goingDate):Observable<Iflight> {
    return this._http.get<Iflight>(this.url +'/' + from +'/' +to +'/' + goingDate+'/' ,
      this.requestOptions)
    .pipe( 
      tap((data) => console.log(this._http + JSON.stringify(data['Quotes']))),
      catchError(this.handlerError)
    );
  }
```

and this is the subscription:

```
searchFlight(from,to,goingDate,):boolean {
   this._skyScannerApiService.getFlightsData(from,to,goingDate,)
      .subscribe(
        (flightData) => { 
          this.flightsData = flightData['Quotes'];
          console.log(this.flightsData);
        },
        (error) => (this.errorMessage = <any>error)
      );
      this.loading = false;
      return false;

  }
```

and this is the html part

```
<div class="col-sm-3 " *ngFor="let flight of flightsData " [p]="flight">
            <div>
                <label>
                <span style="font-size: 100px; ">{{flight.MinPrice}}</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3 ">

                <button class="btn btn-success " style="min-width: 100px; ">Fly</button>

            </div>
        </div>
```

**Updated**

basically I want to access the MinPrice from the api response(flightsData)

here is the response I get from the api.

```
 {
"QuoteId": 1,
"MinPrice": 466,
"Direct": false,
"OutboundLeg": {
"CarrierIds": [
1126
],
"OriginId": 67764,
"DestinationId": 47874,
"DepartureDate": "2021-05-05T00:00:00"
},
"QuoteDateTime": "2021-05-02T12:06:00"
}
```

Comment: Please include your html too and the result your get. Do you get an error or does it simply not show what you expect it to?

Comment: hey @ShamPooSham just added the html, no thing is shown! any thing after the NgFor not showing

Comment: what is result of console.log(this.flightsData); ?

Comment: just added that too! @sankasanjeewa

Comment: is that what you have mentioned? (this.flightsData)

Comment: yes @sankasanjeewa

Comment: to use "ngFor", this.flightsData should be an array like this

[
  {
  "MinPrice": 466,
  ...
 },
  {
  "MinPrice": 466,
  ...
 },
 ...
]

Comment: @Omar Have you taken a look in the web console? You should get an error there.

Comment: no, I've not got any errors @ShamPooSham

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things to consider

1. The return statement inside the `searchFlight()` function isn't doing what you think would be done. Once the function is called, the subscription will take some time to enter it's callback as it's asynchronous. But the `return false` will be triggered immediately.
2. Similarly, the `loading = false` will be called immediately even before the variable `flightsData` is assigned any value. Here you could use the `finalize` operator.
3. To get an array of all the `MinPrice` properties, you could use `Array#map`. It'd give you something like `[466, 466, 466, ...]` i.e. an array of `MinPrice` values.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
minPrices = [];

searchFlight(from, to, goingDate, ): void {          // <-- don't return anything
  this._skyScannerApiService.getFlightsData(from, to, goingDate, ).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.loading = false),
    map((flightData) => flightData['Quotes'].map(quote => quote['MinPrice']))
  ).subscribe(
    (minPrices) => {
      this.minPrices = minPrices;
      console.log(this.minPrices);
    },
    (error) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  );
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 " *ngFor="let price of minPrices " [p]="price">
  <div>
    <label>
      <span style="font-size: 100px; ">{{ price }}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 ">
    <button class="btn btn-success " style="min-width: 100px; ">Fly</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @MichaelD but your solution did not work

Comment: @Omar: What exactly did not work? Did you get any error message or was the output empty?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, this.flightsData is actually not an array, but an object? if so, try this with the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

```
searchFlight(from,to,goingDate,):boolean {
  this.flightsData = this._skyScannerApiService.getFlightsData(from,to,goingDate,).pipe(
    map(flight => flight["Quotes"])
  ) 
}
```

```
<div class="col-sm-3 " *ngFor="let flight of flightsData | async">
```